# Update field with custom types in JOOQ/PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, ltree

There is a table in PostgreSQL with ltree field. How to update this field with string value?

```
DSL.using(configuration)
.update(AREAS)
.set(AREAS.TREE, area.getTree());//getTree() return String
```

I tried several variants:

1. `val(area.getTree()).cast(field("ltree"))` throwing

   ```
   A org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException has been caught, 
   SQL [update "public"."areas" set "tree" = cast(? as any) where "public"."areas"."id" = ?]; 
   ERROR: syntax error at or near "any"*
   ```
2. `inline(String.format("CAST(\'%s\' AS ltree)", area.getTree()))` using excess quotes

   ```
   A org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException has been caught, 
   SQL [update "public"."areas" set "tree" = 'CAST(''1.35.1284739'' AS ltree)' where "public"."areas"."id" = ?]; 
   ERROR: syntax error at position 4*
   ```
3. `val(field("CAST({0} AS ltree)", area.getTree()))` throwing

   ```
   A org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException has been caught, 
   Type class org.jooq.impl.SQLField is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
   ```

Comment: Can you please specify which version of JOOQ and PostgreSQL you are using?

Comment: Jooq version 3.6.4, PostgreSQL 9.6.2, driver version 42.1.4.jre7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Thorough solution

In the long run, the best approach to add support for vendor-specific data types is to specify a [custom data type binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) for it, which allows you to define how jOOQ should serialise / deserialise the type to the JDBC API, including the cast that you might need.

A quick win might be these:

```
field("CAST(? as ltree)", area.getTree());
field("CAST({0} as ltree)", val(area.getTree()));
```

#### This is why your various attempts didn't work:

```
val(area.getTree()).cast(field("ltree"))
```

That approach seems to make sense at first, as you're using jOOQ's built-in `cast()` support. However, your `field("ltree")` expression models a field *named* `ltree` of an unknown type, so when you pass that to `cast()`, jOOQ doesn't know what to cast the `val` to, thus: `any`

```
inline(String.format("CAST(\'%s\' AS ltree)", area.getTree()))
```

This doesn't really make sense in your context, because [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-java.lang.String-) creates an inline bind variable, or constant, or *a string literal* (all different names for the same concept). You don't want a string literal `'CAST(... AS ltree)'`, you want the expression `CAST(... AS ltree)`.

```
val(field("CAST({0} AS ltree)", area.getTree()))
```

That's similar to the above, although you were close here. The inner `field(...)` expression creates a SQL template, which is what you wanted. But then you wrapped that in a bind variable using [`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val-T-), which doesn't really make sense for two reasons:

- You don't want your cast expression to be a bind variable
- The cast expression (of type `Field`) is not a valid type to create a bind variable from. jOOQ doesn't know how to bind a value of type `Field`

Comment: Thank you for answer! It was necessary only to cast the type `(Object)field("CAST(? AS ltree)", tree); ` Sorry for the trouble